# HTML Convertir una div en un enlace clickeable

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en html, y no encuentro una forma de convertir un `div` con texto en un enlace clickeable.

El objetivo es convertir esa `div` en una especie de tarjeta clickeable con función de enlace.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado, para poder ayudarte, que forma no lo tienes claro? Puedes darle a **editar** y añadir el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
te dejo como hacerlo con js o html puro, el css es de ejemplo nomas
```

```js
const divDom = document.getElementById("clic");

divDom.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  //enlace de la pagina que quieras
  window.location.href = "https://www.luofluck.tech"; 

});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.box-2{
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="clic" class="box"> haz click en mi para redigir con javascript </div>
<a href="www.paginaquequieras.com">
<div id="clic" class="box box-2"> haz click en mi para redigir con HTML </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coje el elemento que quieras que sea un enlace y empaquetalo dentro de la etiqueta `a` *example*

```
<a href="link del enlace">Hola Mundo</a>
```